# Joomla 3 get profile

Tags: joomla, get

I use function `onUserAfterSave` and `$isnew`, but I can't get phone and address of user registered in Joomla 3.X. I only can get name, username, email, but no data from profile.

Answer (score 0):

To access the user profile data you need to use JUserHelper class

```
jimport( 'joomla.user.helper' ); 
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$userProfile = JUserHelper::getProfile( $user->id ); //Get userprofile data
//You can get all the user input of profile data. If you want to get country of user use
echo "Country :" . $userProfile->profile['country'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Amit Ray,

I use in my plugin:

public function onUserAfterSave($user, $isnew, $success, $msg)
    {
        //die(print_r($user));
        if ($isnew){ 
.............

```
        $pluginParams = new JRegistry($plugin->params);

        $name           = $user['name'];
        $name_usuario   = $user['username'];
        $email_user     = $user['email'];
        $id_usuario     = $user['id'];
```

jimport( 'joomla.user.helper' );

$user = JFactory::getUser();

$userProfile = JUserHelper::getProfile( $id_usuario );

//You can get all the user input of profile data. If you want to get country of user use

$user_phone = $userProfile->profile['phone'];

$user_address   = $userProfile->profile['address1'];

But $user_phone and $user_address no have data... whats is error? Thanks